# Using Intellij to create React app

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2017

I'm creating a React app.

I have the javascript language version set to React JSX in Preferences > Languages & Frameworks.

I have restarted Intellij

I'm still getting an error 'Expecting new line or semi colon' when using 'let' in Javascript files.

How do I fix this

I'm getting the error after the `let`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Projects extends Component {

    let projectItems;

}


render(); {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
        <div className="Projects">
            My Projects
        </div>
    );

}

export default Projects;
```

Comment: Please include the simplest code sample that you believe should work, but produces this error.

Comment: This isn't a properly constructed React class.

Comment: I know it's not but would that give me the error after the `let`

Comment: You're getting exactly the error you should. JS classes must contain methods, not standalone properties like `projectItems`